# How to pass values from a file to another file in ajax and should go to the previous page?

Tags: php, ajax

I have written a code to send some values from one php file to another php file using ajax. I want to send these values but the control should be in the second php file. and should go to the first php file.

Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

```
  $.ajax({


                                type: "POST",
                                url: "request.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(resultt){



                                }
                        });
```

request.php

```
<?php




$formPostUrl = "https://www.citruspay.com/gggg";    



$secret_key = "ggggggg";    



$vanityUrl = "ggggg";


$merchantTxnId = "p".time(); 



$orderAmount = $_SESSION['pprice'];

$currency = "INR";

$data= $vanityUrl.$orderAmount.$merchantTxnId.$currency;



$returnUrl = "http://dfdfdfd/response.php";

$securitySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret_key);

 ?>


  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

      <form align="center" method="post" action="<?=$formPostUrl?>">
         <input type="hidden" id="merchantTxnId" name="merchantTxnId" value="<?=$merchantTxnId?>" />
         <input type="hidden" id="orderAmount" name="orderAmount" value="<?=$orderAmount?>" />
         <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="<?=$currency?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="<?=$returnUrl?>" />
         <input type="hidden" id="notifyUrl" name="notifyUrl" value="<?=$notifyUrl?>" />
         <input type="hidden" id="secSignature" name="secSignature" value="<?=$securitySignature?>" />
         <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="<?=$email?>" />
         <input type="hidden" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" value="<?=$tel?>" />





         <input type="Submit" class="pay" value="Pay Now"/>
     </form>
```

I want to send the values stored in dataString, also I want to make the second file that is request.php visible not the first php file. control should go to the second file and should return to the second file.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Hi..Nobody here....